# Convert from Python long int to unsigned int 64 with Swig

Tags: python, swig

I am developing a Python library using Swig.
I have a typemap similar to the following:

```
%typemap(in) (unsigned long long myLongParam){
   $1 = PyInt_AsUnsignedLongLongMask($input);
}
```

I am calling the target Python function like this:

```
#Calling with a very large integer
myFunc(0xFFFFFFFF11111111L)
```

This is supposed to be a 64 bit long unsigned integer. However, the value seems to be truncated 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
The problem was not there. The problem was elsewhere, not related to the above code.
I was doing the following wrong code:

```
%apply int* OUTPUT {Uint64*}
```

This tells swig to treat Uint64 the same as int, therefore the result was truncated. It was using SWIG_From_int to the result value.

My solution was:

```
/*Uint64* parameter as reference */
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) Uint64* (Uint64 temp) {
    temp = 0;
    $1 = &temp;
}

/*Uint64* as function return typemap*/
%typemap(argout) Uint64* {
    %append_output( PyInt_FromLong( *$1 ) );
}
```